# Pytest and pytest-django ends up with assert error

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I've been dealing with this for the last 30 mins and I just want to move on from it. Basically, the test returns Assertion Error:

```py
E       AssertionError: assert {} == {'rant': 'Kulugo', 'slug': 'apostrophe'}
E         Right contains 2 more items:
E         {'rant': 'Kulugo', 'slug': 'apostrophe'}
E         Full diff:
E         - {'rant': 'Kulugo', 'slug': 'apostrophe'}
E         + {}

tests/rants/test_serializers.py:26: AssertionError
```

Now tracing back the error in line 26: `assert serializer.data == invalid_serializer_data`

I expect everything to pass since this written code is based on a tutorial from testdriven.io

Here's the full code:

```py
from main.serializers import RantSerializer, CategorySerializer


def test_valid_rant_serializer():
    valid_serializer_data = {
        'id': 1,
        'title': "First Rant",
        'slug': "first-rant",
    }
    serializer = RantSerializer(data=valid_serializer_data)
    assert serializer.is_valid()
    assert serializer.validated_data == valid_serializer_data
    assert serializer.data == valid_serializer_data
    assert serializer.errors == {}


def test_invalid_rant_serializer():
    invalid_serializer_data = {

        'rant': 'Kulugo',
        'slug': 'apostrophe'
    }
    serializer = RantSerializer(data=invalid_serializer_data)
    assert not serializer.is_valid()
    assert serializer.validated_data == {}
    assert serializer.data == invalid_serializer_data
    assert serializer.errors == {"id": ["This field is required"]}
```

This is the error:

```py
FAILED tests/rants/test_serializers.py::test_valid_rant_serializer - AssertionError: assert False
FAILED tests/rants/test_serializers.py::test_invalid_rant_serializer - AssertionError: assert {'title': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'categories': [ErrorDetail(st...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the expectation of the test case `test_invalid_rant_serializer`, in this case, you expect the `serializer.data` to be equal to `invalid_serializer_data` but it will not populate the `.data` attribute with the input data.

To fix that we can remove the line that checks for equality between `serializer.data` and `invalid_serializer_data` like that:

```
def test_invalid_rant_serializer():
    invalid_serializer_data = {
        'rant': 'Kulugo',
        'slug': 'apostrophe'
    }
    serializer = RantSerializer(data=invalid_serializer_data)
    assert not serializer.is_valid()
    assert serializer.validated_data == {}
    # Remove the following line
    # assert serializer.data == invalid_serializer_data
    assert serializer.errors == {"id": ["This field is required"]}
```

Comment: I removed that line but it still shows the same error

Comment: Then run the test again and check the output for the serializer.errors and serializer.data. It's possible that there are additional errors in the serializer, or the errors are different from what you expect.

Comment: Errors are still the same. Don't know why it does that